# R plot - multiple categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, categorical-data

I'm a newbie at R and I'm trying to generate a plot based on a dataframe with 3 columns:
Gene (`Character`), Expressed (`Boolean`), Function (`Levels`)

For each Gene I want to generate shape specified by Expressed (`0=circle, 1= square`) and color the shape according to Function (ie different color for each level)

Can anyone recommend a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a blind stab:

```r
set.seed(4)
eg <- data.frame(Gene = paste("Gene", LETTERS[1:4]), Expressed = sample(0:1, size=4, replace=TRUE), Function = paste0("F", 1:4))
eg
#     Gene Expressed Function
# 1 Gene A         1       F1
# 2 Gene B         0       F2
# 3 Gene C         0       F3
# 4 Gene D         0       F4

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(eg, aes(Gene, y=1)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(Expressed), colour=Function), size=4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("0"="circle", "1"="square"))
```

[image]